# Get Inventory Running Balance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

So heres the problem. I have the following temp table

```
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
| Date       | Name    | Reference | In  | Out |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
| 2015-10-28 | Sample1 | Invoice1  | 100 | 0   |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
| 2015-10-29 | Sample1 | Release1  | 0   | 100 |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
| 2015-10-29 | Sample1 | Invoice2  | 200 | 0   |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
| 2015-10-29 | Sample1 | Invoice3  | 300 | 0   |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
| 2015-10-29 | Sample1 | Release2  | 0   | 300 |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+
```

I need to compute the running balance. This has already been ordered correctly

```
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+---------+
| Date       | Name    | Reference | In  | Out | Balance |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+---------+
| 2015-10-28 | Sample1 | Invoice1  | 100 | 0   | 100     |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+---------+
| 2015-10-29 | Sample1 | Release1  | 0   | 100 | 0       |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+---------+
| 2015-10-29 | Sample1 | Invoice2  | 200 | 0   | 200     |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+---------+
| 2015-10-29 | Sample1 | Invoice3  | 300 | 0   | 500     |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+---------+
| 2015-10-29 | Sample1 | Release2  | 0   | 300 | 200     |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----+-----+---------+
```

Currently using Cursor for this but Im not sure if this is the right implementation. I call this procedure everytime they need a report so it might have performance issues

**UPDATE:**

Found another way to do this. Is this better than using cursor or WITH statements?

```
DECLARE @RunningBalance decimal(18,2)

SET @RunningBalance = 0

UPDATE @StockInvetoryReport
SET @RunningBalance= Balance = ( @RunningBalance + [In] ) - [Out] 
OPTION (FORCE ORDER);

SELECT * FROM @StockInvetoryReport
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a subquery for giving a distinct id/RowNo to your data. Then use the subquery in a CTE by referring it twice and making sure you join them on Name and the distinctid columns as shown.

```
;WITH mytable AS
(SELECT 
    Date
    ,Name
    ,Reference
    ,In
    ,Out
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date,Reference) AS RowNo
)
SELECT 
    a.Date
    ,a.Name
    ,a.Reference
    ,a.In
    ,a.Out
    ,SUM(b.In) - SUM(b.Out) Balance
FROM   
    mytable a,
    mytable b
WHERE 
    b.RowNo <= a.RowNo
    AND b.Name = a.Name
GROUP BY 
    a.Date
    ,a.Name
    ,a.Reference
    ,a.In
    ,a.Out
    ,a.RowNo
ORDER BY 
    a.RowNo
```

Comment: Performance wise. Is this better than declared variables? Please see update

Comment: I have seen better performance with the join method rather than the cursor. However, you could test and let us know the results.